# Variable Christoffel symbol to structure constants

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given the following Christoffel symbols for a metric on $\mathbb{H}^3$, how do I obtain the structure constants $C^i_{jk}$, such that $[\theta_i,\theta_k] = C^k_{ij}\theta_k$, and get the to agree with what I have? :

$$\Gamma^3_{11} = z^{-1}, \Gamma^1_{13}=-z^{-1}, \Gamma^3_{22}=z^{-1}$$
$$\Gamma^2_{23} = -z^{-1}, \Gamma^1_{31} = -z^{-1}, \Gamma^2_{32} = -z^{-1} $$
$$\Gamma^3_{33} = -z^{-1}$$

I have seen formulae such as $\Gamma^i_{jk} =\frac{1}{2}(C^i_{jk}+C^k_{ij} + C^k_{ji}) $, but I have already calculated these $C^i_{jk}$ using Bianchi classifications and they are just a bunch of $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: What Lie group are you talking about here? I only know "structure constants" in the context of Lie groups. And if the $\theta_j$ are invariant $1$-forms, what does the bracket mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin, Bianchi group of type V, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_classification

Comment: Ah, the Heisenberg group. Your structure equations still make no sense, because you're mixing differential forms and vector fields? Can you please write down the metric and your work?

Comment: I just realised something about my whole problem that changes it dramatically. Can you put the quesiton on hold?

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona You can delete the question yourself (and reinstate it once you are ready).

Comment: (But the short answer to your question is that you need to compute $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ in an invariant frame for them to be constant.)